# <TemplateResponse> object does not have attribute data in Unit test in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Hi guys im trying to run some unit testing based on this view here in django but it gives me the error **AttributeError: 'TemplateResponse' object has no attribute 'data'**.
I tried to print the content or context from the TemplateResponse object but it does not retrieve the object date in order to assertEqual (compare) the data.

I also tried to return a response object in the view but still getting the same error.

```
class PostList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = JobPostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_superuser:
            return JobPost.objects.all()
        else:
            return JobPost.objects.filter(author=user)
```

This is the unit test snippet code.

```
class PostListTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.author = NewUser.objects.create_user(
            email='testuser@testuser.com',
            user_name='test11',
            first_name="test11",
            password='Family123!')
        self.superuser = NewUser.objects.create_superuser( email='admin@admin.com',
            user_name='admin',
            first_name="admin",
            password='Family123!')
        self.post1 = JobPost.objects.create(title="Job Post 1",
            place="Test Place 1",
            description="Test description 1",
            job_date="2023-05-20",
            status="undone",
            slug="job-post-1",
            reward=1,
            author=self.author,)
        self.post2 = JobPost.objects.create( title="Job Post 2",
            place="Test Place 2",
            description="Test description 2",
            job_date="2023-05-22",
            status="done",
            slug="job-post-2",
            reward=1,
            author=self.superuser,)

    def test_get_queryset_superuser(self):
        self.client.login(email='testuser@testuser.com', password='Family123!')
        response = self.client.get('')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        queryset = JobPost.objects.all()
        serializer = JobPostSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)

    def test_get_queryset_author(self):
        self.client.login(email='admin@admin.com', password='Family123!')
        response = self.client.get('')
        print(response)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        queryset = JobPost.objects.filter(author=self.author)
        serializer = JobPostSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, serializer.data)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `response = self.client.get('')` will trigger that API view. It looks like it is rendering a function-based view in Django, not your `ListAPIView`.

Comment: It actually returns a 200 response because the the api view its empty itself like this,   path('', PostList.as_view(), name='listcreate'),